# For и метод index для списка

Tags: python, list, for, index

Допустим есть список:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5,6,2,7,8,9]
```

как получить индекс каждого объекта '2' в списке при помощи цикла for и метода index

Comment: `res = [i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x == 2]` Я бы не стал использовать `list.index()` для этой задачи...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласен с *MaxU*, но если нужно через `index()`, то можно таким образом поступить.

`index()` имеет параметры `list.index(element, start, end)`. Ищем первое вхождение, добавляем к его положению следующую позицию и ищем уже с нее.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5,6,2,7,8,9]
search = 2
loc = 0
for _ in range(mylist.count(search)):
    loc = mylist.index(search, loc)
    print(loc)
    loc += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

В целом согласен со всеми людьми выше, но хотел бы продемонстрировать хороший метод, а также то, как решить задачу в поставленных условиях. Постараюсь расписать максимально подробно

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9] #исходный список
sind = [] #множество индексов вхождения
el = 2 #искомый элемент 
ind = 0 #индекс элементы
for _ in range(mylist.count(el)): #кол-во итераций - кол-во вхождений элемента в список
    ind = mylist.index(el, ind) #первый аргумент - искомый элемент, второй - стартовый индекс
    sind.append(ind) #добавляем индекс в список индексов
    ind += 1 #прибавляем к индексу 1, что бы не проверять элемент, который уже найден
print(*sind) #эта функция распаковывает список как список аргументов
```

А теперь перейдём к "хорошему" решению

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9] #исходный список
sind = [] #множество индексов вхождения
el = 2 #искомый элемент 
for i in range(len(mylist)): #проходимся по всему списку
    if mylist [i] == el: #проверяем элемент на сходство с искомым
        sind.append(i) #добавляем индекс с искомым элементов в список
print(*sind) #эта функция распаковывает список как список аргументов
```

Но если совсем постараться.. То можно в одну строку!

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 9] #исходный список
el = 2 #искомый элемент
print(*[i for i in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[i] == el])
```

По факту это тоже самое что предыдущее решение, но думаю вам, как начинающему программисту, будет не лишним увидеть и данный вариант решения.

Удачи в изучение Pyhton!

Comment: Благодарю за столь подробный ответ. Yor're breathtaking! Есть ли название у конструкции в последнем варианте?

Comment: Конечно! Это называется генератор списка. Лично я всегда называл это "в**ть фор в одну строку", но правильно всё таки так)) Что бы понять лучше, вот ссылки на доп. материалы: https://python-scripts.com/for-in-one-line (довольно понятно, но не максимально подробно), https://habr.com/ru/post/320288/ (очень подробно, но возможно будет сложно), https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/generatory-spiskov-v-python (очень понятно, но не то что бы сильно подробно).